# Java shows ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but index exists

Tags: java

I'm writing a small Java program which should display Pascal's triangle.

When I launch the program, I get the right output `1`, then it crashes with the exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`. Apparently, it is caught the second time the outer loop under `// Assigning values` is initialized, when pretending to write data into the array element with the index `[1][0]`. However, the latter was initialized at the beginning of the program.

Classes in the package:

1) `testclass` - the main one

2) `factorial` - includes the `factmet` method calculating factorials

Code of the main class (printing section was skipped because or irrelevancy) :

```
class testclass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Creating the array
    int doubledim[][] = new int[10][];
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        doubledim[k] = new int[k + 1];
    }

    // Assigning values
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < j + i; j++) {
            if (factorial.factmet(j + 1) - factorial.factmet(i - j) == 0) doubledim[i - 1][j] = 1;
            else doubledim[i - 1][j] = factorial.factmet(i) / (factorial.factmet(j + 1) - factorial.factmet(i - j));
            System.out.print(doubledim[i - 1][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
}
```

How to avoid the exception and make this stuff work? Thanks.

Comment: At what line does exception occur? It's in the stack trace or directly in the debugger.

Comment: Sorry, line with `else doubledim[i - 1][j]`. Here, it's #14.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, so I guess that in the debugger.

Comment: `j < j + i; j++ `  makes no sense to me - it's equal to `0 < i` (if there is no overflow)

Comment: how can: for (j = 0; j < j + i; j++) terminates?

Comment: Use a debugger to see where your assumptions fail to match reality.

Comment: Together with the outer loop, the program assigns values only to valid indexes. For example, i = 1, then the inner loop begins with j = 0 and continues till j < 1, so effectively is executed just once. If i = 2, the inner loop goes from j = 0, then j = 1 until the condition j < 2 is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `for (j = 0; j < j + i; j++) {` has very strange condition `j < j + i`. In any case, it will overcome permitted `j+1` length of underlying array.

Comment: Yes. j < j + i is always true because 1 <= i. You stuck in an infinite loop and IndexOutOfBoundsException stops your program.

Comment: Thanks guys... that was a typo. I somehow confounded i + 1 with j + i. Now it works.